# $2 (field reference) in awk BEGIN is not working

Tags: shell, scripting, awk, ksh

In the following snippet, `$2` in awk is returning empty. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to find the difference between MAX and MIN.

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: sh `basename ${0}` filename";
        exit 1;
fi
if [ ! -s ${1} ]; then
        echo "file doesn't exist or is empty";
        exit 1;
fi
sed -e '/^$/d' -e '/^#/d' ${1} |
awk  -F'=' '
        BEGIN {
                MIN=$2; MAX=$2; print MIN;
        }
        {
                if ( $2 > MAX )
                {
                        MAX = $2;
                }
                else if ( $2 < MIN )
                {
                        MIN = $2;
                }
        }
        END {
                DIFF=MAX-MIN; print "DIFF:" DIFF;
        }
'
```

However, this is working fine. Why doesn't `$2` work in the `BEGIN` section?

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: sh `basename ${0}` filename";
        exit 1;
fi
if [ ! -s ${1} ]; then
        echo "file doesn't exist or is empty";
        exit 1;
fi
sed -e '/^$/d' -e '/^#/d' ${1} |
awk -F'=' '
        {
                if ( MAX == "" || MIN == "" )
                {
                        MAX = MIN = $2;
                }
                else
                {
                        if ( $2 > MAX )
                        {
                                MAX = $2;
                        }
                        else if ( $2 < MIN )
                        {
                                MIN = $2;
                        }
                }
        }
        END {
                DIFF=MAX-MIN; print "DIFF:" DIFF;
        }
'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BEGIN` patterns are executed **before** any input is read, so consequently none of the variables that refer to input, like `NR`, fields like `$0`..., will be defined in any of the `BEGIN` blocks.  Your second approach is correct and much better.¹  From the [POSIX awk spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03) (*emphasis* mine):

> The awk utility shall recognize two special patterns, BEGIN and END. Each BEGIN pattern shall be matched once and its associated action executed *before the first record of input is read* ...

<sup>¹ Just a side note, it's also good because it doesn't make assumptions about the minimum or maximum being bounded by a particular value like 0, something many one-liners one finds on the internet assume.</sup>

Comment: BEGIN patterns are executed before any input is read -- unless I use getline.. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a command on the first line of input text, you should use `NR==1` pattern, not `BEGIN`.

```
awk  -F'=' '
    NR==1 {
            MIN=$2; MAX=$2; print MIN;
    }
    NR>1 {
            if ( $2 > MAX )
            {
                    MAX = $2;
            }
...
```

As stated by @jw013, `BEGIN` pattern is for actions to execute before you read the first line.

Comment: You could avoid the `NR>1` test by ending the first block with `next`.